# Rails models reloaded mid-request resulting in AssociationTypeMismatch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

We've been running into a problem in Rails 3.1 when we run in development mode.   It seems that our models sometimes get reloaded mid request, and a new object_id is set on our model's classes.  Which then results in an ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch

> ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch Character(#2194222580) expected,
>   got Character(#2185863000)

If we turn `config.cache_classes = true` in `development.rb` the problem seems to go away, but it's unrealistic to develop like that as we'll have to constantly be restarting our servers.

Anybody have an idea why models may be reloaded mid request, or if there is a way we could force the cache to last through the entire request?

Comment: try active_reload gem it's cache the model,and expires when any changes is done in dev mode.I don't know why it changes run time.can u try and let me know this help for last issue

Comment: I think that looks like it's working, we're on rails 3.1 right now and apparently active_reload is included by default in rails 3.2.

It's a bit hard to consistently reproduce, but I'll update this question if it looks like it's gone in a few days.

Comment: active_reload does not work unfortunately.  Though we may not have configured it properly

Comment: Just wondering, do you have any calls to 'load' or 'require_dependency' instead of 'require' ?

Comment: Maybe a silly suggestion, but do you have any monkey patching on your Models, or any files that are required in your controllers or views. According to `ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch` this shouldn't happen if your classes get reloaded but rather when associating an unexpected object type.. Would it be possible your associations are getting changed by anything?

Answer (score 1):

With config.cache_classes = false, any change to the model causes a reload.  This includes defining/redefining a constant defined in/known to the model.

We had this problem using rspec and ActsAsFu.  Redefining the Fu class during the test caused related (even indirectly related) classes to reload, and we got the ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch error on the related object.  We figured this our because we had tests that ran fine alone, but failed when running after other tests.  Our solution was to just create separately-named Fu classes for each configuration, and avoid reassigning the class name during the test.

So my recommendation is to make sure you are not redefining any constants known to your Character class (or known to classes known to your Character class, etc.)

Comment: This seems to be just a different slice at @stuartc's explanation.  (i.e. monkey patches redefining the Model definition, OR the definition of related models.)  

Same mechanism... changing a model mid-test forces cascading reloads.

Answer (score 0):

In the past I've found that reopening (monkey patching) an ActiveRecord model will actually reload the entire class from top to bottom. Try searching your codebase for more than one instance of `class Character`.